# Potential for disaster: Xcode displays other projects source file for editing

Tags: xcode, relative-path

I was trying to extract a tiny fraction of my project for error investigation, when Xcode surprised me with a very puzzling behavior.

- I created a new single view project in a separate folder with the default settings (in this case storyboards and ARC) and no class prefixes.
- in Finder I copied the 2 class files in question from my main project folder to my new project folder. **EDIT: here is my error, I did not do it in Finder and in Xcode I forgot to
  select the "copy if needed" checkbox. Next time, I will double-check
  or really do it in Finder...**
- in Finder I copied the binaries of a library I am using to a sub-folder of my new folder.
- I added the library to the new project
- I added the 2 class files to my new project
- I started Product -> Build for -> Running to find the first basic errors

The first error Xcode gave me was in a file in my old project folder. The "AppDelegate.h" of course is named the same. Why shouldn't I do that, after all? Xcode was using the other paths file and of course it did not fit my new project. When I tapped the error, it actually displayed the other projects file for editing!

If I had not seen that it was the wrong file (I had not edited the AppDelegate.h of the new project yet), I might have edited the file of the other project, creating havoc! This really gives me the shivers.

I checked it with "Show in Finder": it really is the file in the other folder that has nothing whatsoever to do with my currently opened project. I already tried "Clean" and deleting the derived data. Renaming the file of the other project did work - that cannot be considered a solution!

Has anyone seen this behavior before? Stubbornly I refuse to let Xcode dictate my file names. Apart from that, how can I prevent this behavior? Well, what **is** this behavior??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake: I did NOT go to Finder to copy my files, no matter what I believe to remember. I must have done it in Xcode AND THEN forgotten to select the "Copy items to destination folder (if needed)" checkbox.

So, if ever you get this behavior: first look at your project folder. Are the files you believe are there really there? Or have you just linked files that are somewhere else into your project? Or even better: use Finder to copy your files and add them afterwards, like I WANTED to do it, but seem to have forgotten.